# webpack - UgifyJS fails

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I am trying to add an UglifyJS plugin to my webpack config. The entry point is simple and looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Comp from './components/comp.vue';
Vue.component('somecomponent', {
    render: h => h(Comp)
});
```

and when I try to run webpack it throws an error:

```
ERROR in source1.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: operator (>) [./frontend/source1.js:7,0][source1.bundle.js:80,15]
```

What am I missing? this is my config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        source1: './frontend/source1.js',
        source2: './frontend/source2.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/bundles')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['static/bundles']),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader', 
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uglify DOESN'T handle ES6 currently, So before putting anything through UglifyJS you need to first have it transformed down to ES5. Generally you'll do that with babel-loader.

check https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: if we lazy load a node_modules which is of es6 then that file won't be transpile to
es5 then uglifyjs giving error how to handle that scenario

Answer (score 0):

UglifyJS does support arrow functions, but maybe it doesn't like your short hand way of writing it.   Do you get the same result with...

```
Vue.component('somecomponent', {
    render: (h) => { h(Comp) }
});
```

You shouldn't have to do this and if this works and not the other way it's most likely a bug with Uglify.js.

Comment: Yep, I got the same results. However, I added Babel loader and "es2015" preset, and the error disappeared. Thanks!